# Can I make an address link activate a javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have this code:

```
<input id="doCheck" type="button" onclick="doCheck('a'); return false;"  />
```

But I want to convert this to use an address link and not an input because I have created my own class btn and I want to use that.

```
<a class="btn" href="@(Model.NextUrl)" title="Go to next">&gt;&gt;</a>
```

Is it possible to do this. To make the clicking on the link activate Javascript. Also can I stop Google from getting interested in the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, you can add the onclick to the anchor:

```
<a class="btn" href="@(Model.NextUrl)" title="Go to next" onclick="doCheck('a'); return false;">&gt;&gt;</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="ht..com" onclick="doCheck('a'); return false;" rel="nofollow">Link text</a>
```

the `onclick` can be used here
`rel="nofollow"` will tell google jnot to 'click' the link

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The `onclick` attribute [may be used with most elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html).

```
<a class="btn" href="@(Model.NextUrl)" onclick="doCheck('a'); return false;"
   title="Go to next">&gt;&gt;</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

By adding the `onclick` to your hyperlink, you avoid Google from tracking the address of the link since the JavaScript is not contained in the `href`. Either way, Google doesn't track JavaScript in `href`s anyway.

```
<a class="btn" href="@(Model.NextUrl)" title="Go to next"
    onclick="doCheck('a'); return false;">&gt;&gt;</a>
```

Alternatively, you can add a `rel` tag to any anchor that tells Google not to track the address of the hyperlink:

```
<a class="btn" href="@(Model.NextUrl)" title="Go to next"
    onclick="doCheck('a'); return false;" ref="nofollow">&gt;&gt;</a>
```